# Error occurs while importing DXA publications

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, sites-9.5

Download DXA from: https://github.com/RWS/dxa-web-application-java/releases/tag/DXA_2.2

An error occurred while importing DXA publications with the command below:

```
'.\cms-import.ps1 -importType all-publications -cmsUrl "https://tridion.xxxxx.xxx" -cmsUserName "******" -cmsUserPassword "*******"'
```

Error message:

```
2021/11/18 14:09:23 <80> [Error] Tridion.ContentManager.InvalidUriException: No items found for WebDAV URL(s): /webdav/110%20DXA%20Site%20Type/Building%20Blocks/Framework/Developer/Templates/JSON.tptcmp.
at Tridion.ContentManager.UrlConversion.Convert()
at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.UpdateInternal(IdentifiableObjectData deltaData)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetNewObject(IdentifiableObjectData data)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.AbortErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical, UserReply additionalUserReplyOptions)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.CreateImportAction.Perform(IdentifiableObjectData itemData)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItems(IList`1 items, Boolean specialGroupImport)
at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.Import(String packageName)
2021/11/18 14:09:23 <80> [Information] Transactional import failed at 11/18/2021 2:09:23 PM(+0000). No changes were committed to Tridion Sites Content Manager.
```

However, it succeed when I tried the 4th time without changing anything.
Any ideas on what leads to this error?

Answer (score 2):

"Unresolved dependencies" ... do you have **the three specific error messages** - I wonder if each import brought in a dependency that was required until all dependencies where in place? The only other reason I could see it failing intermittently would be

- access issue (network) access issue
- content porter already running

  - perhaps it was running as a service in the background the first three
    times
  - *but the error doesn't really lean to that*

Comment: thank you, Dylan.   The first 3 times failed with the same error mentioned above in Error message.

Comment: As you can see in the log, the import is done transactional, meaning that if something goes wrong, the entire import is rolled back. So, I don't expect each attempt to change the state of the system.  I cannot explain the observed behavior; I have never seen this happening myself, despite having observed thousands of imports.